# how to add while or foreach loop in json array?

Tags: php, json

how to add foreach or while loop in json

```
$p = $db->query("select * from person");
        $json['result'] = '1';
        $json['message'] = 'Record founded';
        $json['data'] = while($row = $p->fetch_array()){
        $user_result = $row['f_name'].',';
        echo $user_result; 
        };
```

i want get output like this.

```
{
        "result": "1",
        "message": "Record  founded"
        "data":"name1,name2,name3,name4";
    }
```

Comment: a while doen't return anything. So you have to fill the var _inside_ (or after) the loop.

Comment: how to get data without while

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$p = $db->query("select * from person");
$json['result'] = '1';
$json['message'] = 'Record founded';

$values = []; // initialize an array
while($row = $p->fetch_array()){
    //extract($rp); // don't know what this is for here

    // fill the array
    $values[] = $row['f_name'];
}
// implode it to a string with commas in between
$user_result = implode(",", $values);

$json['data'] = $user_result;
```

Anyway, - depending on your situation -  I'd recommend to put the whole array `$values` into `$json['data']` if you wanna use that data later, and only implode to string with comma when you actually output the data.

Answer (score 1):

If you need that exact output you can do like this :

```
 $string = "";
 while($row = $p->fetch_array()){
     $string .= $row['f_name'] . ',';
 }
 $string = rtrim(",", $string);
 $json['data'] = $string;
```